# hide element by checkbox html and php only

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I wanna make a checkbox that when user check and submit its appear specific elements.

this is the selection form in admin.php

```
    <form action="/html/codes/html_form_handler.cfm" method="get">
<input type="radio" name="page_type" value="adv" > advertisement<br>
<input type="radio" name="page_type" value="ann" > announcement<br>
<input type="radio" name="page_type" value="pic" > picture <br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and the selected part will be shown in user.php. each option has its own php file so I got 3 files adv.php, ann.php and pic.php. and using `<?php include 'adv.php'; ?>` to show in user.php

any suggestion how to do it ??

Comment: why different files? you can show data in one single file

Comment: because I'm using it in another pages. so by <?php include 'adv.php'; ?> much easier

Answer (score 0):

Update your form like this;

```
<form action="/html/codes/html_form_handler.cfm" method="get">
<input type="radio" name="page_type" value="adv" > advertisement<br>
<input type="radio" name="page_type" value="ann" > announcement<br>
<input type="radio" name="page_type" value="pic" > picture <br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And at the backend;

```
$pages = array ("adv", "ann", "pic");

$page_type = $_GET["page_type"];
// Validate page type
if (in_array($page_type, $pages)) {
    include $page_type . ".php";
} else {
    die("Invalid page type");
}
```